# Loading error for simple_form in Rails 3.2.8 engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form, rails-engines

When loading simple_form in our Rails 3.2.8 engine, the simple_form initializer file simple_form.rb causes error:

```
/config/initializers/simple_form.rb:2:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant SimpleForm (NameError)
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
```

Under engine's config/initializers, the simple_form.rb is:

```
# Use this setup block to configure all options available in SimpleForm.
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  # Wrappers are used by the form builder to generate a
  # complete input. You can remove any component from the
```

The `SimpleForm.setup do |config|` causes the error. tried to add engine namespece as `RfqxEmc::SimpleForm.setup do |config|` and the error is the same.

What's the right way to install/load simple_form in Rails engine?

Comment: Did you do? rails generate simple_form:install

Comment: Yes, simple_form.rb under config was generated after this rails g command.

Comment: Since the rails generate simple_form:install create initializer for simple form. I have the feeling that the rails g command is not needed here for the engine. When the engine is mounted in a rails app, rails g could generate the initializer file and be used for the engine as well. Can someone confirm that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [post](http://blog.jamesalmond.com/using-simple-form-in-an-engine/) talking about simple_form for rails engine. Just add require 'simple_form' in simple_form.rb.

Answer (score 0):

If the accepted answer doesn't work and you're creating an engine, I had to install the gem in my application as well. I'm too green to know if there's a way to inherit gems from an engine in an easier way. Requiring 'simple_form' in the config/application.rb didn't work, nor did I need to require simple_form in my initializers.