# New to Ruby on Rails; starting tutorial and can't connect to localhost:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using a mac to start the rails tutorial by daniel Kenoe. I ran into a problem within the first few steps of starting the tutorial. I can not connect to localhost:3000

Attached is the code:

```
Micahs-MacBook-Air:learn-rails micahcrews$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.6 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/micahcrews/workspace/learn-rails/config/initializers/simple_form.rb:2:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant SimpleForm (NameError)
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/micahcrews/workspace/learn-rails/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/micahcrews/workspace/learn-rails/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from /Users/micahcrews/workspace/learn-rails/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/micahcrews/workspace/learn-rails/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/micahcrews/workspace/learn-rails/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@learn-rails/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/micahcrews/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading error for simple\_form in rails 3.2.8 engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633195/loading-error-for-simple-form-in-rails-3-2-8-engine)

Comment: how would I remove the duplicate if there is one?

Comment: If the referenced question has an acceptable answer for you, you can "agree" with the duplicate, to link to it from this question.